# Angular JS UI Bootstrap tabs (ui.bootstrap.tabs) causes page to scroll/jump on select

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Selecting tabs causes the page to scroll randomly for e.g selecting a tab can scroll the page almost all the way to the top then I would have to scroll down to see the content of the tab, if I select another tab the page scrolls again.

The tabs' content is of variable size some having more elements than others so they are naturally of different heights but I am not sure if this is the reason of the random page scrolling.

I tried some jquery to disable the link default actions with no luck.

```
$(function () {
   $('body').on('click', 'a[ng-click="select()"]', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

The other solution  which is ugly is that I wrapped the tabset in a div and set a height on the div

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="profile-nav-tabs" style="
         height:500px;
         overflow-y: auto;
         overflow-x:hidden
         ">
        <tabset justified="true">
            <tab  heading="{{::strings.profile}}">
                <br />
                <div  ng-include="'tab-profile.php'"></div>
            </tab>
            .... more tabs
       </tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: I applied a min-height to the tabset itself (<tabset style="min-height: 800px;>)
This is working in my case. For me it was only a problem if the tabset was the last element of the page. Obviously tabs are loosing their height during change. This causes the page itself to change its height.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. After tracing the code, I think this is a bug of `tabset` directive.

The solution is (step-by-step):

1. Modify `tabset.html`, delete `[ng-class="{active: tab.active}"]`
2. Modify `[tab]` directive's `scope.$watch('active')`'s handler.
3. Use `angular.element`'s `addClass` and `removeClass` function to add/remove `active` class.

   ```
   link: function(scope, elm, attrs, tabsetCtrl, transclude) {
   scope.$watch('active', function(active) {
       /*if (active) {
         tabsetCtrl.select(scope);
       }*/
       var idx = tabsetCtrl.tabs.indexOf(scope);
       var elmPane = angular.element(elm[0]).parent().next().children()[idx]; //li->ul->div(tab-content)->div(tab-pane)
       if (active) {
           tabsetCtrl.select(scope);
           angular.element(elmPane).addClass('active');
       }
       else {
           angular.element(elmPane).removeClass('active');
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Could you please explain how the `active` class assignment was causing the page to scroll and how your method avoided this behavior?